# Placing a single checkbox in Bootstrap's navbar form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know whether it's a bug or I'm missing something.

Please have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/8ypj0x5b/8/ (expand the view area so that menu doesn't get collapsed)

```
<div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
  <!-- This dummy div is necessary for the checkbox to show up correctly -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="unv form-control"/>
  </div>

  <!-- Loses vertical alignment w/o the preceding form-group -->
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Test1
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the only workaround I found to place a single(!!) checkbox in a nav bar form. If you remove `form-group` with invisible input, then checkbox immediately loses vertical alignment. Are there any other ways of doing that?

Comment: you can set "display: inline-block;" to your div, https://jsfiddle.net/8ypj0x5b/10/

Comment: @this.girish to which one?

Comment: remove form-group of your div and put style="display:inline"

Comment: @this.girish I don't need the form-group at all, but without it checkbox isn't centered.

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8ypj0x5b/11/  you can achieve this without using a form-group